# Using @string resource inside a style definition

Tags: android, string, resources, coding-style

I have something like the following (shown below) defined in my styles.xml file.  But Android crashes due to the use of the @string/fontExtraLarge. I'm assuming it's because of the order of definition, but is this legal.

I could use the style 'parent' attribute to resolve this, but for only one style definition doesn't make sense.  Is there a way to resolve this problem.

BTW, the error I get is Unable to Inflate XML which points to the layout.XML, but really this file is causing this issue.

```
<!-- **** FONT SIZES **** -->
<string name="fontExtraLarge">20sp</string>
<string name="fontLarge">18sp</string>
<string name="fontMedium">16sp</string>
<string name="fontSmall">10sp</string>
<string name="fontNormal">10sp</string>'

<style name="screenHeader">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">serif</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@string/fontExtraLarge</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the dimens.xml file for dimension values

then reference it @dimen/yourDimensionName

[More details here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension)

Comment: Thank you.  [http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SoftKeyboard/res/values-land/dimens.html](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SoftKeyboard/res/values-land/dimens.html)

Answer (score 0):

All strings go inside res/values/strings.xml.

Also all style tags have to be enclosed with the `<resources/>` tag.

Comment: 1) I tried with the strings defined in the styles.xml and the values.xml file with no change. 
2) There is a resource tag around my definitions. 

My application does work without the string definitions. So it is not a syntax issue.  It is strictly an issue with using @string within a style definition.

Comment: My bad. Didn't see that you were setting the string values as dimensions.