# Can I read a string from string.xml file for text color?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to read a text color from string file for my style right now I am doing

```
<style name="xxx" >
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
</style>
```

I want to do

```
<style name="xxx" >
    <item name="android:textColor">@string/whiteColor</item>
</style>
```

want to read text color value from string file

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why from strings and not from colors.xml, which is intended for this ?

Comment: I don't think that's possible, you can use `@color/whiteColor`.

Comment: Possible duplicate [Using @string resource inside a style definition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423365/using-string-resource-inside-a-style-definition).

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it, try this

```
<string name="grey">@color/col</string>
<color name="col">#ffffff</color>
```

Now you can use the string grey instead of col to add the color
OR

```
 <string name="grey">#ffffff</string>
    <color name="col">@string/grey</color>
```